# Compute $\sum_{k=-1}^{n=24}C(25,k+2)k2^k$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem

> Compute $\sum_{k=-1}^{n=24}C(25,k+2)k2^k$

Well, I've found a solution for it, but I don't understand the line in the orange rectangle, can anyone exlain it please?

[image]

Comment: Is it the equality in the middle of the line that you don’t understand?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott The right side of the equation.

Comment: Making the substitution you need to : 1) replace everywhere $k$ with $t-2$ and also $2)$ make sure the range of summation is right : $k$ ranges from $-1$ to $24$ so $t$ ranges from $1$ to $26$ .Also after that in the same line the sum is splitted in two parts because of that $t-2$

Comment: @ComplexPhi I do not understand the splitting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{t=1}^{26}\binom{25}t(t-2)2^{t-2}&=\sum_{t=1}^{26}\left(\binom{25}tt2^{t-2}-\binom{25}t2\cdot2^{t-2}\right)\\
&=\sum_{t=1}^{26}\binom{25}tt2^{t-2}-\sum_{t=1}^{26}\binom{25}t2^{t-1}\\
&=\sum_{t=1}^{26}\left(\binom{25}tt2^{t-2}\cdot 2\cdot\frac12\right)-\sum_{t=1}^{26}\left(\binom{25}t2^{t-1}\cdot 2\cdot\frac12\right)\\
&=\frac12\sum_{t=1}^{26}\binom{25}tt2^{t-1}-\frac12\sum_{t=1}^{26}\binom{25}t2^t\\
&=\frac12\sum_{t=1}^{25}\binom{25}tt2^{t-1}-\frac12\sum_{t=1}^{25}\binom{25}t2^t\;,
\end{align*}$$

where the last step is because $\binom{25}{26}=0$ anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much! Highly appreciated.

Comment: @Ilan: My pleasure!

Comment: ֲ@Brian Do you think it is possible to solve it with differiation? For e.g., puting $1/4$ outside of the sum so we stay with $2^t$ and getting somehow rid of $(t-2)$..

Comment: @Ilan: It’s possible to start with $\sum_{t=1}^{25}\binom{25}tx^t=(x+1)^t-1$, divide by $x^2$, differentiate with respect to $x$, multiply by $x$, and set $x=2$, but it’s a fair bit of work.